# Why do I get a Parse error on date field

Tags: soql, query, date

I have the following simple query but i am getting a parsing query error, any ideas?

```
SELECT startDate__c  FROM invoice__c WHERE startDate__c.month() = 3
```

startDate__c is a date field. No errors if i remove the WHERE startDate__c.month() = 3 part

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use Date functions in SOQL, the supported syntax is documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm). The correct syntax:

```
WHERE CALENDAR_MONTH(StartDate__c) = 3
```